# Increase Java heapspace: Eclipse vs. BAT-script

Tags: java, heap-memory

I would like to increase the Java heap space for a program in Eclipse. Increase the heap space with `-Xmx1500m` in the virtual machine arguments is no problem, but I get the following error if I increase it with 6 GB:

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx6G
>
> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

The problem does not occur if I export my developed program and run it as jar file in a bat-script in the console.

Does somebody know why this problem only occurs in Eclipse?

My system:

- Windows 7, 64Bit
- 16GB RAM
- Eclipse Juno, 64Bit

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://edwards.sdsu.edu/labsite/index.php/daniel/236-increasing-heap-size-in-eclipse)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is telling you that `-Xmx6G` is too big for the JVM executable that Eclipse is trying to start.  The fact that it is complaining for a number this small tells me that Eclipse must by trying to launch a 32-bit JVM rather than a 64-bit one.  By contrast, when you run from the command line you are getting a 64-bit JVM.

My conclusion is that you have both 32 and 64 bit JRE / JDK installs, and you've somehow configured Eclipse to use a 32-bit JVM for applications.

(I'd also try that with a lowercase 'g' ...)

Answer (score 3):

Try to read this document: http://javahowto.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html .Where it is providing the 6 commonest errors related with Java Heap Size settings. In your occasion the problem is the following one:

Problem: The heap size is larger than JVM thinks you would ever need. For example:

```
   java -Xmx256g BigApp
   Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx256g
   The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
   Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Solution:

```
The fix is to lower it to a reasonable value: java -Xmx256m BigApp
```

Comment: Yes.  That is >>a<< fix.  But it is not >>the<< fix, because in this case the OP needs to run Eclipse with a large heap.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Stephen C!

Somehow there were two JREs installed (I assume by strange updating). A complete reinstalling of Java solved the issue. However I couldn't just change the JRE in eclipse...

Comment: Since we are using this tool for some data mining tasks we need a lot of memory. So we really need this amount of RAM to received well trained models.